# Plotting the highest negative and highest positive Values in one Graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tibble

I have the following output in R:

```
> beta_wide
# A tibble: 547 × 4
   term        topic1  topic2 log_ratio
   <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 russia    1.46e- 2 0.0430      1.56 
 2 ukraine   1.76e- 2 0.0292      0.728
 3 people    1.23e- 2 0.00922    -0.412
 4 it’s      9.20e- 3 0.00307    -1.58 
 5 ukrainian 9.20e- 3 0.00154    -2.58 
 6 allies    8.72e-35 0.0184    107.   
 7 united    8.43e- 3 0.0169      1.00 
 8 russian   1.07e- 2 0.00614    -0.804
 9 president 9.20e- 3 0.00307    -1.58 
10 security  1.15e- 2 0.00922    -0.319
# … with 537 more rows
```

I now want to rank and plot the 10 highest negative *and* the 10 highest positive log_ratio values in a ggplot. The resulting plot should look like this example:

[image: image of example].

I came up with the following code:

```
beta_wide %>%
  mutate(term = reorder(term, log_ratio)) %>% 
  filter(log_ratio[1:10]) %>%
  ggplot(aes(log_ratio, term, fill = log_ratio)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~term, scales = "free") +
  scale_y_reordered()
```

Obviously, this code is all wrong, it results in no output. R just continously calculates it and then even crashes sometimes. Could someone help me please figure this out?

Thanks!

(Full disclosure: I am a beginner in R)

Comment: Perhaps `beta_wide %>% slice_max(abs(log_ratio), n = 10) %>% ...`

Comment: ` slice_max(abs(log_ratio), n = 10)`  is a good hint, but it will not answer OPs Question correctly as OP needs the best 10 Positive and negative values. `n=10` will only provide 10 Values and even with more `n`  `slice_max`  might put the top n Values aout and not the bottom n. Think ov Values of [-1,100]. In that case only top values woulfd be in `abs(values)`

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

First, we load all required libraries and generate the data. I do not have your data so i am making my own.

```r
library(tidyverse)


# artifical Data, dont worry about it
mydata <- data.frame(
  term = replicate(1000,{
    paste0(sample(c(LETTERS,letters), replace = T,size = 10), collapse = "")
  }),
  log_ratio = runif(1000, min = -1))
```

Now we filter the top and bottom 10 vaules of `log_ratio`

```r
filtered <-mydata %>% 
  # Rank enumerates values by their rank (the lower the number , the lower the rank)
  filter(
    ( 10 >= rank(log_ratio)) |  # We want the low ranks  OR ("|")
      (rank(log_ratio) > nrow(mydata)-10) # the high ranks
    )
```

NOTICE: This might not result in 20 Values exactly, because of tie handling in the ranking function if there are identical `log_ratios` in the top or bottom `n`. for now we assume there are no duplicated values.

```r
# using the filtered data we can put the im ggplot
ggplot(data = filtered,
       mapping = aes(
         x = log_ratio,
         y = reorder(term,log_ratio) # rorder the y axis by the ascending value in
         # the corresponding log ration ("-log_ratio" if descending)
         )
       ) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE)+
  ylab(NULL) # do not show Label of Y
```

You cannot combine `%>%` and `+` within the same context (maybe you can, but its not trivial), so just make two lines out of it.